# Insert to table or update if exists using MYSQL database

Tags: mysql

I have mysql database. I need to update country list on my table. there is some country in my table. I need to check that country if not exist and insert to the table. I'm used following sql script. But this is not working. when execute this code it will duplicate the record.

MySQL Query:

```
INSERT INTO `moneyexpressstore`.`countries` (`Name`, `Code`, `CurrencyId`) VALUES
    ('Australia', 'au', NULL) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Name=VALUES(Name)
```

thanks,

Comment: is your structure table have primary key?

Comment: Do you have unique indexes in that table (needs to be `Code`, I guess) ?

Comment: because key on that query refer to primary key.. impossible to have duplicate record

Comment: @RonaldAlexanderKailola: not necessarily primary key. Any unique index will do.

Comment: @sergio yes sorry my mistake

Comment: In My table already have Primarykey and Indexes

Comment: @user2710638: show output of `show create table countries`

Comment: '235', 'AUS', 'Australia', NULL
'243', 'au', 'Australia', NULL


this is output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure your database does not have duplicate records on column `countries`, then execute this

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX countriesindex ON countries (Name(50))`

50 is the amount of characters that the index will search for "unique" values. For example if that number was 3, then these two different string would be considered the same, and a `1062 Duplicate Entry` error would occur `abcHELLO=abcWORLD` and in your case it would force the `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`.

If you get a 1062 error, that means you have duplicates in your db so find them remove them and try again.

After this your query will execute just fine and will update instead of duplicate on "Name"

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the documentation of mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert into `moneyexpressstore`.`countries` (id, `Name`, `Code`, `CurrencyId`) values(NULL,'Australia', 'au', NULL) on duplicate key update name=values(name)
```

Please refer this link:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html